# Microsoft Integration Server Error Saving data. Problem with date data type

Tags: datetime, ssis

Im runing a SISS that read several txt with some data, the first 50 files went fine, but, when I get to december data I get this error:

There was an error with input column "fecha" (1206) on input "OLE DB Destination Input" (79). The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

The format of the date type is like this: 01-dec-10 and Im trying to save the data in a data base whick date field is a simple data type.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that 01 could be the year or 10 could be the year and it doesn't know which one to use. Try and update the data to be 2001-dec-10 or 01-dec-2010 whichever it needs to be and run it again.